# Update hidden values during form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I'm trying to update 2 hidden values with a lat and lng from Google geocoder.

```
<input id="userlat" name="userlat" type="hidden">
<input d="userlng" name="userlng" type="hidden">
```

The values are updating fine but it isn't posting the data. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, guessing my ordering isn't correct?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.directory-search.mapping').submit(function(e){
        var postal = $('#loc').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(postal) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postal, componentRestrictions: { country: 'UK' }}, function(results, status) {
                var lat = $('.directory-search.mapping').find("input[name=userlat]");
                var lng = $('.directory-search.mapping').find("input[name=userlng]");
                lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                return true;
            })
        this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `geocoder.geocode` is likely an asynchronous method, meaning you are submitting your form here _before_ the result has actually been retrieved and put into your hidden fields. Submit the form from within the callback function of that method instead, after you set the hidden values.

Comment: try to use [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to help you out

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to move the

```
this.submit()
```

inside .geocode() callback function, since the function is asynchronous and the submit gets executed before the function finished.

You just need to take care of the "this", it will not be recognized inside the callback.

A small hack to overcome this is setting up the "this" before the function:

```
var test = this;
```

and then call the submit inside the callback like this:

```
test.submit();
```